# Do the Time Lords have a flag?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

<sub>Prompted by a recent question in chat...</sub>

**Is there a Gallifreyan flag?** Or a flag for the ruling organisation of Time Lords? If so, **what does it look like?**

Both sides often have flags in wars, so the existence of the Time War suggests there may have been a Time Lord flag, even if Daleks consider themselves above such things ("Da-leks have no con-cept of el-eg-ance" - Doomsday, 2006). What's the most canonical answer for whether there is one and how it looks?

Comment: They have a "seal"; http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Seal_of_Rassilon

Comment: Ask Sheldon Cooper, PhD, he should have some knowledge of *Doctor Who* and *flags* :P

Comment: Why would Time Lords conform to customs of Earth?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a flag and/or symbol in the war room of the Gallifreyan War Council. Has the Seal of Rassilon in the center with a white hourglass shape behind it on a field of red and 5 much smaller gallifreyan symbols near the perimeter (3 on the left, 2 on right).

[image: Gallifreyan war flag]

Comment: There, I added it for you. But can you cite sources on where you saw this flag? Which episode, book or website? From what I could see, the only place it's shown is in a wiki devoted to an online game set in the Doctor Who universe, but is not in the actual show.